# Rails transaction deadlock or something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, locking, pessimistic-locking

I have `User`, `Order`, `Contest` and `Position` models in my Rails app.
There are many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Order` and one-to-many between `Position` and `Order`, `User` and `Contest`.

I have order processor service with `execute` method which processes order. To prevent race condition I use transaction with `lock!` inside.

The problem is that when I'm invoking two or more `execute` method with the same order in argument at the same time sometimes I'm getting deadlock. The strangest thing is that first method starts execution while the second is awaiting for order to unlock. All as expected. But my first method (which is executing) is locking in the middle. And more stranger is that method is locking in lines where not any locked records are processed. Plus the line where method is executing forever can randomly change if I comment some unrelated lines and again sometimes (not always) it is locking on lines which are not changing or even not using any locked records.

Here is my `execute` method

```
  user = order.user
  contest = user.contest
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

    # the second method awaiting here as excpected
    order.lock! 

    # some processing stuff here like
    order.executed = true

    position = find_or_create_position(order)
    position.lock!

    # .where.not(id: order.id) just in case to ignore locked row
    # but based on business logic it can't really be anyway.
    #
    # Plus it is not seems like the reason because 
    # if I comment this and the next lines deadlock occurs later
    open_orders = user.orders.open.where.not(id: order.id)

    # commonly method stops here
    closed_orders = close_open_orders!(order, price, open_orders)

    # method stops here if I comment two lines above
    order.save!

    # I left this line because as I remember once 
    # after some random changes like commenting some lines 
    # I got method stopped even here
    commission = contest.commission * order.count
    closed_orders.each { |closed_order| closed_order.save! }

    # here some position processing and finally
    position.save!

    user.lock!
    # and user processing
    user.save!
  end
```

By processing in comments I mean just assignment attributes to records.

So here is beginning of my `close_open_orders!` method

```
  rest_count = order.count

  # here it stops. each just stops without any iteration. 
  open_orders.each do |open_order|
```

But I don't think that the problem is in `each` statement because as I said I'm getting deadlock if I ignore this method.

And everything works ok when only one method is executing. 
I can also attach pg logs but I don't see any deadlocks there: two selects of orders for update. than select for `user.orders.open.where.not(id: order.id)` and that's all. After that unrelated (or not?):

```
03:58:13 [21231-1] LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'UTF8'
03:58:13 [21231-2] LOG:  statement: set client_encoding to 'unicode'
03:58:13 [21231-3] LOG:  statement: SET client_min_messages TO 'warning'
```

I can add some more pg logs if needed.

**UPD** I'm using sidekiq to execute jobs asynchronously

Comment: what does `closed_shorts` method look like?

Comment: @MoustafaSallam closed_shorts just returns some other orders which are not blocked 100%. And as I said this line even not starting

Comment: @MoustafaSallam updated code to make it more clear and simple.